# Como mantener la persistencia de datos al implementar widgets en Wordpress 5.6 Guntenber?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Compañeros, al momento de guardar los widgets en el editor de Wordpress este no mantiene los widgets que fueron guardados anteriormente, al instante de recargar desaparecen!!!! ... Su ayuda con la solución de este inconveniente.

Muchas Gracias

Al guardar el widget.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al recargar la pagina. Desaparecen los cambios y por lo tanto no se muestran en el proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el Codigo del "functions.php", sin embargo ya no se que debo realizar.
Al momento de recargar la pagina, se desintegran los widgets, como explique anteriomente. Muchas Gracias por su ayuda.

```
<?php


function pizzashop_setup() 
    {
        // Set the Images Prominet Support
        add_theme_support("post-thumbnails");

        // The the title of the Page 
        add_theme_support("title-tag");

        // Set the image Sizes of the Page 
        add_image_size("imgAboutUsSize", 437, 291, true);
        add_image_size("imgSpecialsSize", 768, 585, true);
        add_image_size("imgSpecialsPortraitSize", 435, 526, true);

    }
    add_action("after_setup_theme", "pizzashop_setup");


/* Initialition Styles and Scripts - Enable the Style Sheet "style.css" */

function pizzashop_styles() 
    {
        // Reset the Style with Normalize
        wp_enqueue_style("normalize", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css", array(), "8.0.1");

        // Insert the google fonts in the Projects
        wp_enqueue_style("googleFonts", "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,800;1,700&family=Raleway:wght@400;700;900&display=swap", array(), "1.0.0");

        // Set the Personal Stytle 
        wp_enqueue_style("style", get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), "1.0.0");


        // Load the File of Scritps 
        // wp_enqueue_scripts("scripts", get_template_uri()."/js/scripts.js", array("jquery"), "1.0", true);


    }
    add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "pizzashop_styles");

   
// Set the Options Menus in WP 

function pizzashop_menus()
    {
        register_nav_menus( array(

            "header_menu" => "Header Menu",
            "socials_networks_menu" => "Socials Networks Menu"
            
        ));
    

    }
    add_action("init", "pizzashop_menus");

// Add the Zonde of Widgets

function pizzashop_widgets()
    {
        register_sidebar( array(
        
            "name" => "Blog Sidebar Widget",
            "id" => "blog_sidebar_widgetId",
            "before_widget" => '<div class="widgetSty">',
            "after_widget" => "</div>",
            "before_title" => "<h3>",
            "after_title" => "</h3>"    
        ));
      
    }
    add_action("widgets_init", "pizzashop_widgets");




// Add the Buttons to the Paginator 

function pizzashop_buttons_paginator() 
    {
        return "class='button_genericSty button_secondarySty'";
    }
    add_filter("next_posts_link_attributes", "pizzashop_buttons_paginator");
    add_filter("previous_posts_link_attributes", "pizzashop_buttons_paginator");



?>
```

Comment: Como estas creando el área de widgets, lo registraste desde tu functions.php, si es asi, puedes compartir el código, también revisa la consola para verificar si tienes errores, intenta instalar el plugin Migrate Helper y verifica si sigue pasando

Comment: Adjunto el codigo del Archivo "functions.php", pero igual ya lo revise, y no se en que parte esta mal. Muchas gracias x tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro, pero creo que podría ser porque no le estas pasando el parámetro ID al widget, cambia tu código de esto.

```
function pizzashop_widgets() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        "name" => "Blog Sidebar Widget",
        "id" => "blog_sidebar_widgetId",
        "before_widget" => '<div class="widgetSty">',
        "after_widget" => "</div>",
        "before_title" => "<h3>",
        "after_title" => "</h3>"    
    ));
      
}
add_action("widgets_init", "pizzashop_widgets");
```

A esto

```
function pizzashop_widgets() {
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'          => esc_html__( 'Blog Sidebar Widget', 'pizzashops' ),
            'id'            => 'blog_sidebar_widgetId',
            'description'   => esc_html__( 'Inserta una breve descriptión', 'pizzashops' ),
            'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widgetSty %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</section>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'pizzashop_widgets' );
```

Los caracteres especiales agregan un identificador al widget basado en su ID, asumo que al no tener un ID WordPress no sabe a que Widget pertenecen los elementos que agrego, por ende, se borran.

Verifique si esto soluciona su problema.